# Swift swipe gesture on UIImageView is not working at all

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uigesturerecognizer

i have the following code but besides everything i tried, the gesture is not recognized on swipeUpDots (there is no "swiped" in console). What should I do, thanks!

I have setupInputComponents() in my viewDidLoad function and it is called correctly.

```
func setupInputComponents() {

    let containerView = UIView()

    view.addSubview(containerView)

    let swipeUpDots = UIImageView()

    swipeUpDots.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "threeDots")

    swipeUpDots.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

    containerView.addSubview(swipeUpDots)

    // Adding swipe functionality

    let swipeUp = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(getSwipedUp(swipeGestureRecognizer:)))

    swipeUpDots.addGestureRecognizer(swipeUp)

    swipeUpDots.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

}

@objc func getSwipedUp(swipeGestureRecognizer: UISwipeGestureRecognizer){

    print("swiped")

    if swipeGestureRecognizer.direction == .up {

        print("Up Swiped")

        // Send Message



    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the permitted direction for your UISwipeGestureRecognizer. In your case:

```
swipeUp.direction = .up
```

Also, I noticed that you have initialized the containerView (UIView) and the swipeUpDots (UIImageView) without defining their frame. When creating a new UIView programatically, you need to tell the system where to draw it and what the rectangle size should be. Here is an example :

```
let rect = CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 100)
let containerView = UIView(frame: rect)
```

For the imageView, set its frame property. For further information, refer to the documentation from Apple :

[UISwipeGestureRecognizer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiswipegesturerecognizer)

[UIView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview)

[UIImageView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimageview)

Comment: Actually  *no*, you *do not* need to do anything more than initialize a `UIView` if you are using auto layout. (In that case you do need to set the view's `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `false`.)

Comment: I wasn't sure if the OP was using auto layout or not. But thanks for clearing it for me!